# How to use a variable inside a RegEx pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

Usage of this code is to show only the last four digits of an input.

Here I want to replace this "(/.(?=.{4})/g, '*')" **'4'** with variable '***mask***' . Something like that.

```
x.value = x.value.replace(/.(?=.{+mask+})/g, '*');
```

Any suggestion plz

```js
function myFunction(mask) {
    var x = document.getElementById("cc");
    x.value = x.value.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, '*');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cc" onkeyup="myFunction(4)" style="text-align:right">
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`new RegExp(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to build a regular expression dynamically. The literal `/../` form *cannot* be used with dynamic content.

Make sure to have a valid pattern after building the string.

```
var len = 99;
var re = new RegExp(".(?=.{" + len + "})", "g");
var output = input.replace(re, "*")
```

Also see (and vote for dupe of):

- [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude. it works now.  "The literal /../ form cannot be used with dynamic content." this line is was the most helpful.

Comment: How does one convert from a literal form to one that new RegExp can use? Just removing the / doesn't seem to work

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez - It depends on what is in the “/ literal /”. The resulting string of the regular expression must be valid.

Comment: Turns out I wasnt escaping some characters I should have. Specifically the backslash